# Display different images in slider as img for mobile and desktop for increased performance

Tags: html, css, image

I have troubles regarding a slider I have on my website.

Currently it's a slider with the `<img>` element. Problem I encounter now is that on mobile the large images get loaded as well. Now I want to load specific (smaller) images for mobile so that my website is faster on these devices.

A solution I had was using the media queries in combination with CSS background image. This is perfect to use because I can load the images with CSS and thus can use media queries to select the image based on screen size.

But the problem is is that I want to add the images to the SEO, they are essential for my website and I  read everywhere that if you have such images, you need to use the `<img>` element. So that the SEO can work and include these images in the content. Also I cannot add ALT tags to background-image.

Another solution is rendering two sliders, one for mobile and one for desktop, and hiding the slider you don't want to see. Problem I have with this solution is that both of the sliders need to render, thus decreasing performance.

Is there a solution that I'm missing here? In my understanding you cannot change images in a `<img>` element with CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `picture` element. As the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) says, "[This element] *serves as a container for zero or more  elements and one  element to provide versions of an image for different display device scenarios*". I think it does the trick. Here you are another good [article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015) that explains how to use this element to achieve the result you need with your responsive images.

Answer (score 0):

The `picture` element is a really nice modern solution. But if you want something more cross-browser, consider an approach with JavaScript. My solution for some websites was using sets of images with regular suffixes, for example `image.jmg`, `image-medium.jpg`, `image-small.jpg`, and a script checking the screen resolution. In the HTML only small images are included, but if the script finds the screen is big enough, it updates their `src` with corresponding suffixes.